# How detect and stop application upgrade to new version android

Tags: android, app-update

I have a very different use-case where I want to check if a user has started to upgrade the application to a particular version and if yes then I want to stop him from doing that.

I have checked the possibility to use `ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED` it only tell me once the upgrade is done. However, I want to stop the upgrade before it is completed.

What I am expecting is a callback method which gets called as soon as app upgrade has started and a method to stop the current upgrade.

Is there any possibility to have this.? or any other approach in which I can achieve this.?

Thanks in advance,
Vishesh.

Comment: If you don't have root access, I don't know any way to achieve this. In general don't publish the app-update. Maybe that's feasible.

Comment: @Christopher   ya sorry no root access.. The problem my application also has Offline support and has offline database and the new version which we have to push will surely have very incompatible changes hence i want to user to logout of the application then update and log back in as during this time i will handle the deletion and re-creation of my Offline database.

Comment: But you'll increase the database version (if you use SQLite under the hood). So, on the upgrade process of the database you may want to logout the user and give him a notice that he needs to login again?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i am trying to do . Actually i am now migrating to a custom domain for my server URL's and as the current offline store are created with old URL's which cannot be used later on hence i want to Inform the user that he should not update the application as it is a in-compatible change and tell him to logout. So that once he logs in again then during that time i will delete all the old database table and stores and re-create them afresh with new server URL's.